# Interpenetrating Solids

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Suppose two right circular cones and one right circular cylinder mutually interpenetrate, with the base of each cone and both bases (i.e., both ends) of the cylinder sealed by precisely fitting flat circular surfaces. What is the maximum number of pieces (i.e., completely bounded volumes) that can thus be formed, considering only the surfaces of these three figures as boundaries and counting only pieces that are not further subdivided?

I tried sketches but to no avail.

Comment: Do you know the answer for generic convex bodies? The answer is the same as in your case.

Comment: @cjackal The answer for generic convex bodies is infinity. Not the case here, though.

Comment: @Ronald What happened to the sketches? Did they catch fire? Or did you destroy them because you didn't like the answer?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Hmm, am I misunderstanding something? The argument I have in mind gives 5 pieces as the answer if there are 2 convex bodies, not 3, does this seem wrong?

Comment: @cjackal Take a pentagonal prism (a convex body, I think). Superpose another similar prism rotated by $36^\circ$ around the 5-fold symmetry axis. How many pieces would that produce?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Oh, you're totally right. My comment should be ignored, sorry bothering you with such a triviality.

Comment: I didn't keep the sketches.  I saw a 3-compound on internet of 3 intersecting cubes and they gave a number of 67 pieces.  For the 2 cones and cylinder I would "suspect" an answer somewhere in the 50s.  I am really looking for a math development -- but no one I ever emailed was able to put a dent into it.  I tried Putnam Fellows, IMO winners.

Comment: I do have a WORD document with the 3 cubes case if someone has an email address.

Answer (score 1):

At least $6$ if one allow the tips of the cones overshoot the other ends of the cylinder.
As shown in the picture below, the surfaces of the $3$ solids is bounding $6$ components:

- $2$ cones sitting on top of the ends of the cylinder.
- $3$ torus with triangle cross section.
- a central piece obtained by gluing two truncated cone along their bases.

[image: 3 interpenetrating solids]